# How to convert button click debounce delay to text box key press delay?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have the following code written to debounce and delay the spamming of button presses:

`app.directive.ts`:

```
// Debounce click method for buttons to prevent spamming during asynchronous function waits

import { Directive, EventEmitter, HostListener, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDebounceClick]'
})
export class DebounceClickDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() debounceTime = 500;
  @Output() debounceClick = new EventEmitter();
  private clicks = new Subject();
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.clicks.pipe(
      debounceTime(this.debounceTime)
    ).subscribe(e => this.debounceClick.emit(e));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  clickEvent(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.clicks.next(event);
  }
}
```

`app.component.html`:

```
<button mat-raised-button appDebounceClick (debounceClick)="buttonPressed()" [debounceTime]="700">Example Button</button>
```

My end goal is to have a text box that will only call a function after the user has stopped typing for a certain amount of seconds (very similar to the button). How would I make a similar directive to instead work for the texting of a text box key press instead of a button click?

**EDIT:**

Here is my current input textbox HTML (not debounced):

```
<form class="form">
  <mat-form-field class="full-width" (keyup)="exampleFunction('exampleInputString')">
    <input matInput placeholder="Input something...">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was fairly simple.

directive.ts:

`// Change click event to keyup event`

`@HostListener('click', ['$event'])` to `@HostListener('keyup', ['$event'])`

component.html:

```
<form class="form">
  <mat-form-field class="full-width" appDebounceClick (debounceClick)="exampleFunction('exampleInputString')" [debounceTime]="700">
    <input matInput placeholder="Input something...">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `debounce` directly with `onChange` even on an `input` works very nicely. Something like this:

`<input type="text" id="myId" onChange={debounce(400, functionToCall())}/>`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to integrate this into my similar solution, could you elaborate in terms of my ```app.component.html```?